# C# Read/Write file from multiple applications

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have scenario where we are maintaining Rates file(.xml) which is access by 3 different application running on 3 different servers. All 3 application uses RatesMaintenance.dll which has below 4 methods Load, Write, Read and Close.

All 3 applications writes into file continuously and hence I have added  Monitor.Enter and  Monitor.Exit mechanism assuming that these 3 operation from 3 different application will not collide. But at this moment, in some case, I am getting error - "**Could not open the rates file**"

As per my understanding, this means, some reason 3 application tries to access at same. **Could anyone please suggest how to handle such scenario?**

```
        Monitor.Enter(RatesFileLock);

        try
        {
            //Open Rates file
            LoadRatesFile(false);

            //Write Rates into file
            WriteRatesToFile();

            //Close Rates file
            CloseRatesFile();
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(RatesFileLock);
        }
```

Method signature of Load-

```
LoadRatesFile(bool isReadOnly)
```

For opening file-

```
new FileStream(RatesFilePath,
        isReadOnly ? FileMode.Open : FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
        isReadOnly ? FileAccess.Read : FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                isReadOnly ? FileShare.ReadWrite : FileShare.None);

.... remaining Rates reading logic code here
```

For reading Rates from file-

```
Rates = LoadRatesFile(true);
```

For Writing Rates into file-

```
if (_RatesFileStream != null && _RatesInfo != null && _RatesFileSerializer != null)
            {
                    _RatesFileStream.SetLength(0);

                    _RatesFileSerializer.Serialize(_RatesFileStream, _RatesInfo);
            }
```

In closing file method-

```
            _RatesFileStream.Close();
            _RatesFileStream = null;
```

I hope, I try to explain my scenario in details. Please let me know in case anyone more details.

Comment: What is in your stack trace?  Likely saying that "file is in use by another process"?

Comment: Also keep in mind that each running process will have their own instance of "RatesFileLock".

Comment: yes...i understand that. This error comes once in a month hence not able to gather stack trace. but surely it is problem with opening the file as it is in use by another application. how do I overcome this?

Comment: You might put in a retry mechanism, up to a certain point of course.  Though that addresses a symptom without really solving the problem.  Files aren't good at concurrent write access.  Maybe save to a database instead?

Comment: Exactly what @David said.  There is no consistent way that you will be able to determine if you can access that file or not.

Comment: In Ideal case, yes I personally go for DB rather than text file. 
but these application takes input files from upstream system, process it, save common rates value in this file and forward it to downstream system. 
Introducing DB layer at this moment is not possible in our case as this is very old system.

Comment: @Sagar: There could be a separate background process (Windows Service perhaps) which polls the database for changes and outputs to the file.  That way only one application actually "owns" writing to the file.

Comment: @David Due to project budget constraints, I cannot introduce database option.

Comment: @Sagar: Maybe take the same approach but with files.  Each application writes to its own file and a background application reads those and writes to a "central file".  'Budget constraints' or not, files are not suited for concurrent writes.

Comment: @Sagar - You do know that `Monitor` only works on multiple threads within a single app? If you have multiple apps it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the other answers are correct and that you won't be able to get a *perfect* solution with files that are accessed concurrently by multiple processes, adding a retry mechanism may make it reliable *enough* for your use case.

Before I show one way to do that, I've got two minor suggestions - C#'s "using" blocks are really useful for dealing with resources such as files and locks that you really want to be sure to dispose of after use. In your code, the monitor is always exited because you use try..finally (though this would still be clearer with an outer "lock" block) but you don't close the file if the WriteRatesToFile method fails.

So, firstly, I'd suggest changing your code to something like the following -

```
private static object _ratesFileLock = new object();

public void UpdateRates()
{
    lock (_ratesFileLock)
    {
        using (var stream = GetRatesFileStream())
        {
            var rates = LoadRatesFile(stream);

            // Apply any other update logic here

            WriteRatesToFile(rates, stream);
        }
    }
}

private Stream GetRatesFileStream()
{
    return File.Open("rates.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
}

private IEnumerable<Rate> LoadRatesFile(Stream stream)
{
    // Apply any other logic here
    return RatesSerialiser.Deserialise(stream);
}

private void WriteRatesToFile(IEnumerable<Rate> rates, Stream stream)
{
    RatesSerialiser.Serialise(rates, stream);
}
```

This tries to opens the file stream once and then reuses it between load and write actions - and reliably dispose of it, even if an error is encountered inside in the using block (same applies to the "lock" block, which is simpler than Monitor.Enter/Exit and try..finally).

This could quite simply be extended to include a retry mechanism so that if the file is locked by another process then we wait a short time and then try again -

```
private static object _ratesFileLock = new object();

public void UpdateRates()
{
    Attempt(TryToUpdateRates, maximumNumberOfAttempts: 50, timeToWaitBetweenRetriesInMs: 100);
}

private void TryToUpdateRates()
{
    lock (_ratesFileLock)
    {
        using (var stream = GetRatesFileStream())
        {
            var rates = LoadRatesFile(stream);

            // Apply any other update logic here

            WriteRatesToFile(rates, stream);
        }
    }
}

private Stream GetRatesFileStream()
{
    return File.Open("rates.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
}

private IEnumerable<Rate> LoadRatesFile(Stream stream)
{
    // Apply any other logic here
    return RatesSerialiser.Deserialise(stream);
}

private void WriteRatesToFile(IEnumerable<Rate> rates, Stream stream)
{
    RatesSerialiser.Serialise(rates, stream);
}

private static void Attempt(Action work, int maximumNumberOfAttempts, int timeToWaitBetweenRetriesInMs)
{
    var numberOfFailedAttempts = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            work();
            return;
        }
        catch
        {
            numberOfFailedAttempts++;
            if (numberOfFailedAttempts >= maximumNumberOfAttempts)
                throw;
            Thread.Sleep(timeToWaitBetweenRetriesInMs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan for your suggestions. I will surely try this.

Comment: @Sagar - were you able to use this to ease your problem? Is there anything that you would like adding or clarifying before accepting the answer?

Comment: I did changed existing code as per your suggestion on Monday 4th July. So far I haven't received this issue in test environment. As this issue occurs very rarely, please give me some more time before I mark as an answer.

Comment: @Sagar - I was thinking about this question yesterday, it's a been more than a month and I was wondering if it seemed to keep your problem under control? I think that everyone agreed that there is no perfect solution with vanilla file access but it would be interesting to know if this solution was "good enough" for your particular use case. Thanks!

Comment: so far issue didn't occurred again. Marking your answer as accepted. thanks once again :)

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is difficult bordering on impossible. I won't say that it's impossible because there is always a way, but it's better not to try to make something work in a way it wasn't intended to.

And even if you get it to work and you could ensure that applications on multiple servers don't overstep each other, someone could write some other process that locks the same file because it doesn't know about the system in place for gaining access to that file and playing well with the other apps.

You could check to see if the file is in use before opening it, but there's no guarantee that another server won't open it in between when you checked and when you tried to open it.

The ideal answer is not to try to use a file as database accessed by multiple applications concurrently. That's exactly what databases are for. They can handle multiple concurrent requests to read and write records. Sometimes we use files for logs or other data. But if you've got applications going on three servers then you really need a database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but due to project budget constraints, I cannot introduce database option.